# Нужно чтоб iframe открывал мобильную версию сайта! На данный момент открывает версию для пк. Как сделать симуляцию мобильного браузера?

Tags: iframe

```
    <div class="screen-container">
        <div>
            <iframe class="bg" src="https://www.inipspace.com"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно явно указать `width` и `height` (ширину и высоту) для `iframe`

```html
<iframe class="bg" src="https://www.inipspace.com" width="360" height="600"></iframe>
```

Или с помощью `CSS`

```css
.bg {
    width: 360px;
    height: 600px;
}
```